# Dense matrix multiplication optimization has small effect in python

Tags: python, optimization, matrix

I would like to know why the Loop optimization inversion on i and j (which should give better data locality) does not work with the following code in python :

```
import random
import time

def fillRand1D(size):
    return [random.uniform(-2.0, 2.0) for _ in range(size * size)]

def mmNaive1D(A, B, size):
    C = [0] * size * size
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            for k in range(size):
                C[i * size + j] += A[i * size + k] * B[k * size + j]
    return C

def mmInvariant1D(A, B, size):
    C = [0] * size * size
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            sigma = C[i * size + j]
            for k in range(size):
                sigma += A[i * size + k] * B[k * size + j]
            C[i * size + j] = sigma
    return C


def mmLoop1D(A, B, size):
    C = [0] * size * size
    for k in range(size):
        for i in range(size):
            for j in range(size):
                C[i * size + j] += A[i * size + k] * B[k * size + j]
    return C


def mmLoopInvariant1D(A, B, size):
    C = [0] * size * size
    for k in range(size):
        for i in range(size):
            Aik = A[i * size + k]
            for j in range(size):
                C[i * size + j] += Aik * B[k * size + j]
    return C

def main():
    matmul_func_1D = [mmNaive1D,mmInvariant1D,mmLoop1D,mmLoopInvariant1D]
    size = 200
    A_1D = fillRand1D(size)
    B_1D = fillRand1D(size)

    for f in matmul_func_1D:
        A = A_1D[:] # copy !
        B = B_1D[:]
        start_time = time.time()
        C = f(A_1D,B_1D,size)
        # print(T)
        print(f.__name__ + " in " + str(time.time() - start_time) + " s")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Results are with python :

```
mmNaive1D in 3.420367956161499 s  
mmInvariant1D in 2.316128730773926 s  
mmLoop1D in 3.4071271419525146 s  
mmLoopInvariant1D in 2.5221548080444336 s
```

Whereas the same optimizations written in C++ give :

```
> Time [MM naive] 1.780587 s
> Time [MM invariant] 1.642554 s
> Time [MM loop IKJ] 0.304621 s
> Time [MM loop IKJ invariant] 0.276159 s
```

Comment: Python lists aren't contiguous arrays, so the optimization doesn't do much here, I'm afraid.

Comment: Oh thanks so if I am using arrays that are contiguous it might work I guess.

Comment: Numpy is a good place to go for optimizing this sort of process if you need to be able to specify contigousness... though of course then you could just use numpy.multiply

Comment: Yes, though with all the type-checking that goes on with python `for` loops, you might not be able to see the advantage of data locality. As en_Knight said, you'd be better off using `numpy` for any real array computations, though I suspect you're just playing around with things.

Comment: exactly I just wanted to play with Python a little bit I will try to use numpy then thanks !

Comment: Using  numpy.ascontiguousarray() does not seem to help... Investigating this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `A, B and C` matrices are python lists, which are quite slow for big dimensions. You could create them as a numpy arrays to try to speed up the functions:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.random.uniform(-2., 2., (size,size))
>>> B = np.random.uniform(-2., 2., (size,size))
```

This defines `A` and `B` matrices as `size x size` random matrices.

The bottleneck of your code are the python loops. Python loops are quite slow, and you want to avoid them in algebraic operations whenever possible. In your case, what you are trying to achieve (if I'm not wrong) is `C = A * B` where * is the dot product between two 2D matrices. Translated to numpy:

```
>>> C = A.dot(B)
```

If you time it:

```
>>> %timeit C = A.dot(B)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.91 ms per loop
```

Takes only `7.91 ms` to calculate the dot product. I know that you wanted to play with python, but if you are going to do mathematical calculus, the sooner you move to numpy the better for your algorithms' speeds.

Going back to your algorithm, if I run your code in my computer, the optimization does work and achieves a bit of speedup:

```
mmNaive1D in 1.72708702087 s
mmInvariant1D in 1.64227509499 s
mmLoop1D in 1.57529997826 s
mmLoopInvariant1D in 1.26218104362 s
```

So it is working for me.

EDIT: After runing the code several times I'm getting different results:

```
mmNaive1D in 1.63492894173 s
mmInvariant1D in 1.1577808857 s
mmLoop1D in 1.67409181595 s
mmLoopInvariant1D in 1.32283711433 s
```

This time the "optimization" is not working. And I guess it is because the bottleneck of the algorithm are the python loops, not the memory accesses.

EDIT2: Some more relevant results performing 100 iterations of each algorithm to get mean timings (took it a while haha):

```
mmNaive1D in 1.66692941904 s
mmInvariant1D in 1.15141540051 s
mmLoop1D in 1.58852998018 s
mmLoopInvariant1D in 1.28386260986 s
```

Even if 100 iterations are still not revelant enough (like 1.000.000 would be better, but it would take ages), it suggest that as the mean of 100 runtimes, the "optimization" is not really an optimization. I don't really know why, but it could be that adding a new variable in python is slower than 200 memory accesses (maybe there is some cache behind it).

Comment: Thank you iluengo for your answer.   Indeed my question was about why the data locality optimizations do not work. I have tried as said in my comments to use contiguous array with numpy.ascontiguousarray without success. I guess you are right the bottleneck is not the memory accesses.

Comment: I just edited with a mean timing of 100 iterations for each of the functions. Hope you find it curious :P